# implicit declaration of function 'runProcessForOneTimeStep' - Multi Level Queue Schedular

Tags: c

I have been stuck with this code for some time and wanted some expert help. Below is part of my code and where the error is coming from:

```
char* simulateNextTimeStep( schedule *ps ) {
    queueType temp, queueFront;
    char *newProcessName = NULL;

    if( !( isEmpty(ps->foreQueue) ) )
    {
        queueFront = ps->foreQueue->qFront->qt;
        newProcessName = runProcessForOneTimeStep(queueFront->processName, queueFront->pData);
        ps->timesteps++;
        queueFront->timeStepsTaken++;
        queueFront->timeStepsTakenInReturn++;
        if( queueFront->timeStepsTaken == queueFront->runtime )
        {
             temp = dequeue(ps->foreQueue);
             freeProcessData(temp->pData);
              free(temp->processName);
               free(temp);
        }
         else if( queueFront->timeStepsTakenInReturn % 5 == 0 && queueFront->timeStepsTaken != 0 && queueFront->timeStepsTakenInReturn != 0 && queueFront->timeStepsTakenInReturn != queueFront->returnStep)
        {
             queueFront->returnStep = queueFront->timeStepsTakenInReturn;
             temp = dequeue(ps->foreQueue);
             enqueue(ps->foreQueue, temp);
         }
     }
     else if( !( isEmpty(ps->backQueue) ) )
     {
          queueFront = ps->backQueue->qFront->qt;
          newProcessName = runProcessForOneTimeStep(queueFront->processName, queueFront->pData);
          ps->timesteps++;
          queueFront->timeStepsTaken++;
          if( queueFront->timeStepsTaken == queueFront->runtime )
          {
               temp = dequeue(ps->backQueue);
               freeProcessData(temp->pData);
               free(temp->processName);
               free(temp);
          }
    }
    if( !( isEmpty(ps->backQueue) ) )
   {
       queueFront = ps->backQueue->qFront->qt;
       if( (ps->timesteps - queueFront->startingTimeStep) >= 50 )
       {
              temp = dequeue(ps->backQueue);
              promoteProcess(temp->processName, temp->pData);
              enqueue(ps->foreQueue, temp);
       }
   }
   return newProcessName;
}
```

This is a Multi Level Queue Schedular that I have been trying to resolve but not able to understand where I can make adjustments and resolve the issue. Although I like to work on just problems on my own, I feel expert help and explanation would be very handy.

Below is the image of the error output:

[image]

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image of text.

Comment: The error is complaining about the declaration of `runProcessForOneTimeStep`; it isn't in your posted code.

Comment: the error message could be better - it actually says 'What The Heck  is runProcessForOneTimeStep? - I have no idea'

Comment: I guess that runProcessForOneTimeStep is in another file and that there is either a header for it that you forgot to include in this file, or that you did not write a header for it at all. You at least need to put a declaration for it at the start of this file

Comment: either that - or its a typo

Comment: The error is telling you that you must explicitly declare `runProcessForOneTimeStep` before calling it.  So, declare it.  If it's defined in another file, then the declaration should be in the corresponding `.h` file, which you need to include.  If it's defined in the same file you're calling it from, then you need to add a forward declaration for it.